# Why deleting cookie file in Safari does not work?

Tags: cookies, safari

I want to delete cookie file in Safari under Mac OS. With the browser shut down, I delete:

```
rm -rf '~/Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/*'                                  
rm -rf '~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/*'                                 
rm -rf '~/Library/Safari/*'                                                  
rm -rf '~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies'                             
rm -rf '~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Safari.savedState/*'
```

but when I start the Safari and run the [test page](http://www.html-kit.com/tools/cookietester/), **still I can see the cookie**. Apparently, it is not deleted...

Any idea why is that? When I delete cookies through Safari options (clear browser data) then all is OK. Although, I am interested in deleting them manually.

Disabling the cookies is no solution - *I want to accept the cookies*, and later I want to delete them. It is because I am automatizing some process and I need to have a clean browser every time

Comment: Have you ever found how to achieve this?